# bike movement feels like the bike's on ice when turning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

whenever I turn my bike it feels like it's sliding. Here's the script

```
    [SerializeField] float turn;
    [SerializeField] float maxSpeed;
    [SerializeField] GameObject bikeParts;
    [SerializeField] float tilt = 20f;
 
    Rigidbody rb;
    float lastY;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float straightMov = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float horizontalMov = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


        ControlStraightMov(straightMov);
        ControlWeightTurning(horizontalMov);

        lastY = transform.position.y;
    }

    private void ControlWeightTurning(float horizontalMov)
    {
        Vector3 bikePartsRot = bikeParts.transform.eulerAngles;
        bikePartsRot.x = tilt * horizontalMov;
        bikeParts.transform.eulerAngles = bikePartsRot;

        transform.Rotate(0f, (turn * Time.deltaTime) * horizontalMov, 0f);
    }

    private void ControlStraightMov(float straightMov)
    {
        if (straightMov > 0)
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce((accel * Time.deltaTime) * -straightMov, 0f, 0f);
        }
        else if (straightMov < 0)
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(((accel / 1.3f * Time.deltaTime) * -straightMov), 0f, 0f);
        }
    }
```

Whenever the bike picks up speed, it becomes very difficult to turn the bike because the force that was added keeps moving the bike in a different direction than the direction the bike's facing, how do I apply that force it was facing before on the direction it is facing now so that it doesn't feel like sliding?

I have tried fixing this problem but i just can't because i am pretty new to unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I apply that force it was facing before on the direction it is facing now

Not sure if this would feel right but you could probably do it like e.g.

```
private void Update ()
{
    ...

    rb.velocity = transform.forward * rb.velocity.magnitude;
}
```

Which will keep the current speed and just redirect it into the new forward direction.

---

In general note: Whenever there is a `Rigidbody` involved you don't want to set any manipulation through the `Transform` component but only via the `Rigidbody`.

So you should not do

```
bikeParts.transform.eulerAngles = bikePartsRot;

transform.Rotate(0f, (turn * Time.deltaTime) * horizontalMov, 0f);
```

but both times rather calculate the target rotation and go through e.g. [`rb.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) in `FixedUpdate`.

Which might look somewhat like

```
float horizontalMove;

void Update()
{
    var straightMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    // Get and store the input in Update
    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    ControlStraightMov(straightMove);
    
    lastY = transform.position.y;
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Handle it in FixedUpdate
    ControlWeightTurning(horizontalMove);
}

private void ControlWeightTurning(float horizontalMove)
{
    var bikePartsRot = bikeParts.transform.eulerAngles;
    bikePartsRot.x = tilt * horizontalMove;

    // Calculate the new final rotation
    var newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(bikePartsRot) * Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * (turn * Time.deltaTime) * horizontalMove));

    // Apply it only via the Rigidbody
    rb.MoveRotation(newRotation);
}
```